# Couldn't execute any function with Elements added by Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, append

I want to dynamically add elements to an existing div by using Jquery. Here is HTML:

```
<div id="color_div" style="min-width: 100px; min-height: 60px; float: left; background: #fff;"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="add_div()" >
Add new Element
</a>
```

Here is Jquery function to add a new element

```
add_div = function(){
    var new_color_div = '<div style="width: 140px;"><input type="text" name="color_name[]" class="product_color_input" /></div>';
    $('#color_div').append(new_color_div);
}
```

Now I want to change input background when typing in it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.product_color_input').each(function(){
            $(this).keyup(function(){
                var code = $(this).val();
                if (code.length==6){
                    $(this).css('background','#'+code);
                }else{
                    $(this).css('background','#ffffff');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't recognized any new element appended to the "color_div" div.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dealing with dynamically added elements, you need to make use of event delegation

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.product_color_input', function () {
    var code = $(this).val();
    if (code.length == 6) {
        $(this).css('background', '#' + code);
    } else {
        $(this).css('background', '#ffffff');
    }
});
```

**Also as a side note**
There is no need to use a `.each()` loop for registering the keyup event handlers, you can make use of the chaining property provided by jQuery and the framework will iterate through each element of the selector set and will register the handler to each of them. So you don't have to iterate yourself

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.product_color_input').keyup(function () {
        var code = $(this).val();
        if (code.length == 6) {
            $(this).css('background', '#' + code);
        } else {
            $(this).css('background', '#ffffff');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot. Just one more question: How can I use jquery colorpicker plugin in my case?

Answer (score 2):

try something like this,Use id (color_div) instead of using document. it will be faster

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#color_div').on('keyup', '.product_color_input', function () {
                var code = $(this).val();
                if (code.length == 6) {
                    $(this).css('background', '#' + code);
                } else {
                    $(this).css('background', '#ffffff');
                }
            });
        });
```